# smsManager doesn't broadcast intent after sending message

Tags: java, android

am trying to send an sms using the sms manager, after sending sms it should broadcast intent to check if a message was sent in the broadcast receiver. the sms is sent using a intentService.

```
public class MessengingService extends IntentService {
    private SmsManager SM;
    private PowerManager powerManager;
    private WakeLock wakeLock;
    public MessengingService() {
        super("messenging service");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Simplify");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent("Message_sent");
        sendIntent.putExtra("phone number", workIntent.getStringExtra("phone number"));
        PendingIntent sendingPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(),Integer.parseInt(workIntent.getStringExtra("phone number")), sendIntent, 0);
        SM = SmsManager.getDefault();
        SM.sendTextMessage(workIntent.getStringExtra("phone number"), null, workIntent.getStringExtra("text"), sendingPendingIntent, null);
        wakeLock.release();
    }
}
```

and I registered the broadcast receiver in the manifest,

```
<receiver
            android:name="hasebou.karim.simplify.MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="Message_sent"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and here is the on receive method of my broadcast receiver

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("Message_sent")){
            Log.e("broadcast", "am sittubg doing nothing");
            switch(getResultCode()){
            case Activity.RESULT_OK: // Sms sent
                notifyMessageSent(MainActivity.thisContext,"Message sent to: "+intent.getStringExtra("phone number"));
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE: // generic failure
                notifyMessageSent(MainActivity.thisContext,"Failed to send message to: "+intent.getStringExtra("phone number"));
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE: // No service
                notifyMessageSent(MainActivity.thisContext,"Failed to send message because no service: "+intent.getStringExtra("phone number"));
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU: // null pdu
                notifyMessageSent(MainActivity.thisContext,"Failed to send message to: "+intent.getStringExtra("phone number"));
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF: //Radio off
                notifyMessageSent(MainActivity.thisContext,"Failed to send message because radio is turned off: "+intent.getStringExtra("phone number"));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the text message get sent correctly? I.e., does the addressee receive the message?

Comment: yes, the addressee receives the message

Comment: turns out for making a broadcast a pending intent should be declared PendingIntent.getBroadcast. I can't answer my own question though because I need a reputation 10 and above

Comment: Yep, I was just typing up an answer that says that. Also, a Service is a Context, so you should use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: but that wouldn't be easily accessible from other classes. I need to be able to stop that message from sending

Comment: I don't know where you got that from, but after you call `sendTextMessage()`, there pretty much is no stopping it.

Comment: sorry I got mixed up. I set alarm using alarmManager to start a service that sends the message. to stop message from I would cancel the pendingIntent that fires the service not the one that smsManager takes